# Removing ssh key value pair

Tags: ssh

I generated new ssh key value pair for logging onto my server. I now want to disable usage of the first key pair cause old users have it and it's a security risk.

How do I do that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a file at `/home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys`. Every line contains a key which is allowed to log in.

If you remove the old key from here and save the file, the old key is useless

Answer (score 0):

Simply replace the old ones with the new ones.